# Bash on Windows 10 - is there way to apply themes like Solarized to cmd?

Tags: windows-10, bash

I'd like to modify the colors of cmd when using Bash as you would on Linux.  Not sure if it's possible or if I should use some emulator app.

Comment: So are you using a bash variant on Windows or are you generally asking about cmd? Open a cmd, left click on the top left and check defaults to set color for every cmd instance.

Comment: Colors were just added a few days ago https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2016/09/22/24-bit-color-in-the-windows-console/#comment-5565 and I asked the guy who announced it a similar question in the comments

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a repo with instructions.

https://github.com/neilpa/cmd-colors-solarized

Answer (score 0):

I made another .reg file color scheme that just makes the colors stronger, because I find the default colors too dark:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console]
"ColorTable00"=dword:00000000
"ColorTable01"=dword:00ff0000
"ColorTable02"=dword:0000ff00
"ColorTable03"=dword:00ffff00
"ColorTable04"=dword:000000ff
"ColorTable05"=dword:00ff00ff
"ColorTable06"=dword:0000ffff
"ColorTable07"=dword:00c0c0c0
"ColorTable08"=dword:00808080
"ColorTable09"=dword:00ff0000
"ColorTable10"=dword:0000ff00
"ColorTable11"=dword:00ffff00
"ColorTable12"=dword:000000ff
"ColorTable13"=dword:00ff00ff
"ColorTable14"=dword:0000ffff
"ColorTable15"=dword:00ffffff
"ScreenColors"=dword:00000007
"PopupColors"=dword:000000f
```

I basically just changed a bunch of 80 hex pairs to ff. Just save it in a file ending in .reg and double click it. You'll have to run cmd via win+r for it to have an effect.